# how to force PageViewer to recreate fragments

Tags: android, fragment

I've got Fragments which can be instantiated in two different ways according to the current layout. 
These fragment are loaded in a `PageViewer` using an Adapter derived from the `FragmentStatePageAdapter`.
If I run the app just in portrait or landscape mode everything is fine. The fragment are loaded correctly and look ok.
The problem is when I change orientation: The fragment doesn't change, it seems that it reuse the one loaded for a certain orientation, in fact if I scroll the pager after the next one (wich it was already loaded in the previous orientation) the new fragment are loaded correctly and when I scroll back again even that "starting fragment" is reloaded correctly.

I would like to fix the problem by forcing the recreation of the current and the adjacents fragments but the solution I've tried seems to be incomplete/not working.

I've overridden the Adapter `startUpdate` method this way:

```
    public void startUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
        if(isPortrait != isLastOrientationPortrait){
            container.removeAllViews();
            instantiateItem(container, lastPosition);
        }
        super.startUpdate(container);
    }
```

This force the elimination of the fragments from the containers. But I don't know if it's a correct approach and how to put the newly instatiated item back to the container.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem:

Instead of extends the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` class I modified its source code (In case you need it you can find it here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java)

What I did was just to modify the `restoreStateMethod` this way:

```
public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
        Log.d(TAG, "restoreState");
        //We don't want to restore the fragments if the orientation changes!
        if(isLastOrientationPortrait != isPortrait){
            if(state != null){
                Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
                bundle.setClassLoader(loader);
                Iterable<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
                if (mCurTransaction == null) {
                    mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                }
                for (String key : keys) {
                    if (key.startsWith("f")) {
                        Fragment f = mFragmentManager.getFragment(bundle,
                                key);
                        mCurTransaction.remove(f);
                    }
                }
            }
            isLastOrientationPortrait = isPortrait;
        }else{
            if (state != null) {
                Bundle bundle = (Bundle)state;
                bundle.setClassLoader(loader);
                Parcelable[] fss = bundle.getParcelableArray("states");
                mSavedState.clear();
                mFragments.clear();
                if (fss != null) {
                    for (int i=0; i<fss.length; i++) {
                        mSavedState.add((Fragment.SavedState)fss[i]);
                    }
                }
                Iterable<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
                for (String key: keys) {
                    if (key.startsWith("f")) {
                        int index = Integer.parseInt(key.substring(1));
                        Fragment f = mFragmentManager.getFragment(bundle, key);
                        if (f != null) {
                            while (mFragments.size() <= index) {
                                mFragments.add(null);
                            }
                            f.setMenuVisibility(false);
                            mFragments.set(index, f);
                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Bad fragment at key " + key);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

what i basically added is this first if statement:

```
if(isLastOrientationPortrait != isPortrait){
            if(state != null){
                Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
                bundle.setClassLoader(loader);
                Iterable<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
                if (mCurTransaction == null) {
                    mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                }
                for (String key : keys) {
                    if (key.startsWith("f")) {
                        Fragment f = mFragmentManager.getFragment(bundle,
                                key);
                        mCurTransaction.remove(f);
                    }
                }
            }
            isLastOrientationPortrait = isPortrait;
        }
```

where `isPortrait` is the boolean value for the current orientation and `isLastOrientationPortrait` is the previous orientation saved via the `onSaveInstanceState`

This force to discard all the saved fragments and recreate them again on orientation change.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn I've changed the answer a little bit to fix a memory leak issue. If you are using my past solution please replace the code with the above.